# Issues with Apache 32 bit on Windows 64 bit

Tags: apache, windows-7, 64-bit

I have a Windows 7 Enterprice 64 bit and with 8GB RAM and I run a localhost with PHP, Apache and MySQL. However, Apache is (officially) still in 32-bit binary. And my system is performing at a enormously low speed... Is this a common problem or are there any tips or trics to boost my performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr version**: It is *not* the 32-bit Apache that is slowing it down.

We would need more information to determine the cause of the problem but my guess is that it isn't the fact Apache is 32bit and Windows is 64bit.

The main difference between 32 and 64bit applications is that 64bit applications can access more memory directly (normally over about 3.5GB).

Apache itself is not particularly slow, it is all the modules you load with it (PHP, Python, mod_rewrite, etc).

It is most likely one (or more) of the following:

- **High Requests/sec** - you have a high number of requests per second
- **High Processing Overhead** - programs/scripts are using a lot of memory/CPU
- **Poorly Written Programs/Scripts** - programs/scripts are inefficient or leaking memory
- **Other Processes** - other programs on your PC (including Windows itself) may be using up your memory/CPU such as *MySQL*

Comment: Ok, makes sense. It's with Drupal 7 websites. Pretty big and complex. But my collegues are running the same website on a Windows 32bit XP... So normally, you would think I got the better system, right?

Comment: Yes and No. Windows 7 uses more memory than Windows XP so if you and your colleagues have the same setup the Windows XP machines would be better.

Comment: If you are looking to speed things up I would recommend looking at your settings for MySQL, PHP and Apache (but specifically MySQL -- giving it more memory). Also take a look in Drupal to see if any caching is enabled as this will help.

Comment: I just gave MySQL 4096MB of memory (more then enough I assume...), but still no notable difference. Do I need to reboot the service in order to get this improvement to work?

Comment: Yes, MySQL won't notice the changes until the MySQL server has restarted. I would recommend googling for 'performance tuning ' and mysql/php/apache as it is not always straightforward. For MySQL tuning I would normally recommend http://www.day32.com/MySQL/ but that only works on from a shell.

Comment: First, find out where the general problem is. Just because the web page is loading slow doesn't mean it is Apache (it is more likely MySQL). Second, debug the specifics (such as timing SQL queries, enabling the `slow_query_log` in MySQL and seeing what that produces, etc.). Finally, fix the problem (for example in MySQL, add indexes, rewrite a query in a better way, etc.). **Fixing the slowness problem** _(especially with no information and via comments)_ **is not going to be possible. All I can say is that it is _not_ the 32bit version of Apache (on 64bit Windows) making it that slow.**

Answer (score 0):

Apache 64bit builds do not generally outperform the 32bit builds by more than 5%.

The only time I've seen a major slowdown running Apache on Windows was due to anti-virus software running.